# Using Pydantic + FastAPI, is there a way to reduce the number of arguments of a classmethod without losing its docs functionality?

Tags: python, parsing, fastapi, pydantic, class-method

I'm resolving a couple of code smells pointed by Sonar. One of them is the amount of arguments on a custom_model class method (model for the data on post/put endpoint). I'm almost convinced it's false positive, but I would like to know if there is a way to make it cleaner.

The method parses each of the model's fields to the fastapi.Form model. It's a classmethod and I don't think there is a way to refactor it without losing the info I need (**kwargs removes the fields required/accepted, so the response turns to 422 always).

Is there a way to make this? Or it's better to just mark it as false positive?

I tried: using **kwargs; changing the default values to the ones returned by the parser; using the default parse_to_obj from pydantic to get the fields and return them parsed as Form.

Then I stopped and moved on to another task, but I'm still curious about the possibility of optimizing it.

example of the method:

```
from fastapi import Form
from typing import Union
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyModel(BaseModel):

    continent: str = Field(default="continent", example="continent")
    city: Union[str, None] = Field(example="city")
    country: Union[str, None] = Field(example="country")
    idh: Union[float, None] = Field(example=10.58)
    population: Union[int, None] = Field(example=600)
    foundation: Union[datetime, None] = Field(example="2022-01-01T00:00:00")
    last_election: Union[datetime, None] = Field(example="2022-01-01T00:00:01")
    zip: Union[str, None] = Field(example="8721108")
    notables: str = Field(example=["Activist", "Athlete", "Businessperson"])
    abbreviation: str = Field(example=["qwe", "rty", "uio"])
    notes: str = Field(example='{}')
    country_code: Union[str, None] = Field(example="qw123")

    @classmethod
    def as_form(cls,
                continent: str = Form("continent"),
                city: str = Form("city"),
                country: str = Form("country"),
                idh: float = Form(10.58),
                population: int = Form(600),
                foundation: datetime = Form("1985-01-01T00:00:00"),
                last_election: datetime = Form("2022-01-01T00:00:00"),
                zip: str = Form("8721108"),
                notables: str = Form('["Activist"]'),
                abbreviation: str = Form('["qwe"]'),
                notes: str = Form('{"test": 123}'),
                country_code: str = Form("qw123")
                ):

        return cls(continent=continent, city=city, country=country,
                   idh=idh, population=population, foundation=foundation,
                   last_election=last_election, zip=zip, notables=notables,
                   abbreviation=abbreviation, notes=notes, country_code=country_code)
```

Comment: See, this is why you should always include the relevant imports. What is `Form`? You mentioned `pydantic.Form` in your post, but there is no such thing in the entire package. Your code examples should always be **reproducible**. This just keeps people guessing what you are talking about.

Comment: Aside from that, I am fairly sure that this code is just wrong to begin with because you are assigning these `Form` instances to fields of a Pydantic model that have totally different types. I expect a call to `MyModel.as_form` to just yield a bunch of validation errors.

Comment: Imports added, I forgot the day I posted.
Again, I'm reviewing an old model - not implemented by me - that currently works as needed. All I'm trying to do is clean the declaration of the method.